# Using a traditional interface for Dexterity schema or XML?

Tags: plone, dexterity

Plone Dexterity supports the definition of the content-type schema either through an interface (using zope.schema for the definition) or through an XML file. What is the preferred/recommended way?

In addition: is there documentation of the XML dialect used for defining a schema (models/mytype.xml) ?

This [presentation](http://shuttlethread.com/blog/beyond-through-the-web-dexterity-types) appears close but not complete.

Answer (score 2):

I personally much prefer the zope.schema route; I can, if I really wanted to, vary the interface attributes dynamically with python, while the XML definition is of course static.

Also, note that to register adapters and views against an XML-defined schema, you need to pull it into python code anyway:

```
from plone.dexterity import api

class IMyXMLDefinedType(api.Schema):
    api.model('my_xml_defined_type.xml')
```

The XML dialect is part of [`plone.supermodel` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.supermodel); I was not able to locate any documentation beyond the [source code](https://github.com/plone/plone.supermodel).

Comment: It's no substitute for full documentation, but check the fields.txt file in plone.supermodel. It reads like a reference showing how supermodel xml equivalents for schema attributes for all the built-in field types.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an interface over an xml model.  Partly that is because I prefer Python over XML.  Partly it is because you cannot do some things with the XML.  For example, if you want to register a field as searchable, with collective.dexteritytextindexer, you (currently) cannot set this in the Plone interface, so you will have to use Python code and therefore an interface.  But Martijn shows in his answer that you can use api.model in an interface to refer to an xml file, so maybe that would be a way around it if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to contribute to the mess by saying there is no hard and fast answer.

With simpler content types, or early in the development of more complex ones, I'm often oriented towards the supermodel XML because of how closely it works with the dexterity TTW editor. It allows me to work with a client with very rapid feedback on what they want from their content type.

Sometimes I'll even move into file system development of some features while still having the fields defined in the FTI via supermodel.

However, with more complex content types, you're nearly certainly going to hit something you can't do via supermodel alone. At that point, I usually translate to schema — and that's typically pretty easy to do.

Ideally, if you're doing a lot of dexterity development, you should probably be able to shift pretty easily back and forth. They're just different ways of representing the same objects and attributes.